# Why we can't use "+" or "-" in console.log()

Tags: javascript, console.log

I am unable to perform addition and subtraction within console.log().
Multiplication and division work as expected.

```js
var x = 100;
var y = 50;

//This Works fine.
console.log('Mathematical Operators : ' + '\n' + 'Multiplication Result : ' + x*y + '\n' + 'Division Result : ' + x/y + '\n\n\n\n');  

//This gives the Output as "NaN".
console.log('Mathematical Operators : ' + '\n' + 'Addition Result : ' + x+y + '\n' + 'Subtraction Result : ' + x-y + '\n\n\n\n');
```

Is there any other way around ?

Answer (score 2):

Take operations into brackets. u are combining string and numbers and getting result from them. so if there is an operation in numbers , u have to take them into brackets. Reason of why first console works that multipulation and division comes before adding or subtraction, so u didn't take any problem there. Don't forget that brackets come before mathematical operations.

U can take a look  the presedence order here
 [info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

```
var x = 100; var y = 50;
console.log('Mathematical Operators : ' + '\n' + 'Multiplication Result : ' +( x*y) + '\n' + 'Division Result : ' + (x/y) + '\n\n\n\n');

console.log('Mathematical Operators : ' + '\n' + 'Addition Result : ' +( x+y) + '\n' + 'Subtraction Result : ' +( x-y) + '\n\n\n\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of operator precedence. Look at the expression:

```
'Mathematical Operators : ' + '\n' + 'Addition Result : ' + x+y + '\n' + 'Subtraction Result : ' + x-y + '\n\n\n\n'
```

This simplifies to:

```
'foo ' + x + y + ' bar ' + x - y + ' baz'
```

Both `+` and `-` have the same precedence, and evaluate left-to-right. When a string is on either side of a `+`, concatenation results:

```
'foo ' + x + y + ' bar ' + x - y + ' baz' // simplifies to:
'foo ' + 100 + 50 + ' bar ' + 100 - 50 + ' baz' // simplifies to:
'foo 100' + 50 + ' bar ' + 100 - 50 + ' baz' // simplifies to:
'foo 10050' + ' bar ' + 100 - 50 + ' baz' // simplifies to:
'foo 10050 bar ' + 100 - 50 + ' baz' // simplifies to:
'foo 10050 bar 100' - 50 + ' baz'
```

But `-` always means subtraction, and strings that can't be converted into numbers can't be subtracted, so it gives NaN as a result. Similarly:

```js
console.log('foo' - 5);
```

Put parentheses around the expressions you want to evaluate first.

```
'Mathematical Operators : ' + '\n' + 'Addition Result : ' + (x+y) +
//                                                          ^^^^^
'\n' + 'Subtraction Result : ' + (x-y) + '\n\n\n\n'
//                               ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use `template literals`

```js
var x = 100;
var y = 50;
const output = `Mathematical Operators :\nAddition Result : ${x+y}\nSubtraction Result :${x-y}`
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thank You for the suggestions. Tried it and it worked.